# how to create an initial prisma migration

Tags: postgresql, prisma, prisma-graphql

I have a PostgreSQL database and prisma schema. My migration history is empty and I don't have migrations table. When I am trying to run `prisma migrate dev` to create migrations table and add initial migration to this table it wants to delete all my database table's data. 
`prisma migrate dev --name migration_name --create-only` command tries to reset my database too.
How to create initial prisma migration without losing my data?
Is it possible to create prisma migrations table in my PostgreSQL database and add initial migration to this table without losing data?
I've tried to follow this article: https://www.prisma.io/docs/guides/database/developing-with-prisma-migrate/add-prisma-migrate-to-a-project but it wants to reset my database after `db pull`.

Answer (score 5):

You can follow these steps to generate the initial migration without resetting your database.

```bash
mkdir -p prisma/migrations/init
npx prisma migrate diff --from-empty --to-schema-datamodel prisma/schema.prisma --script > prisma/migrations/init/migration.sql
npx prisma migrate resolve --applied init
npx prisma migrate dev # it should say everything is in sync
```

Comment: When I am trying to apply this migration it says: Error: P3015 Could not find the migration file at ..\prisma\migrations\init\migration.sql. Please delete the directory or restore the migration file.

Comment: By running which exact command from above do you get this error?

Comment: What is the way to create other migrations after initial migration, is this the same procedure.

Comment: If you are using vscode, try this 
- ctrl + p (cmd + p)
- Write: >change file encoding
- Select Save with Encoding
- Select utf-8

That's work for me

Comment: Note that now the `--preview-feature` flag is no longer necessary.

Comment: @mwieczorek Thanks! Removed the preview feature flag